# confidence intervals (bootstrap in r)

Tags: r, intervals, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have a vector of 19 values. I want to calculate confidence intervals for each value using the bootstrap method. I use the following code:

```
library(boot)
alpha <- 0.9
B <- 1000
p_hat<-s$a     #vector with 19 values
intervals <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = length(p_hat))
 my_function <- function(data, index) {
   return(median(data[index]))
for (i in 1:length(p_hat)) {
 boot_samples <- boot(p_hat[i], my_function, R = B)
 intervals[i,] <- boot.ci(boot_samples, type = "bca", conf = .9)
 }
}
results <- data.frame(p_hat, intervals)
print(results)
```

I get 0 instead of confidence intervals

---

## Data

This is the vector posted in comment.

```
p_hat <- c(0, 0, 6.70881, 14.16335, 26.08988, 41.33073, 57.23204, 
           74.02023, 88.54585, 95.48473, 98.97599, 99.90797, 
           99.94741, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
```

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you post a reproducible example.  try `B <- 4999`.  bca confidence intervals fails with low replications.

Comment: @Eric Thank you. I tried with 4999, but the problem remained. My vector contains the following values : 0.00000   0.00000   6.70881  14.16335  26.08988  41.33073  57.23204  74.02023 88.54585  95.48473  98.97599  99.90797  99.94741 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000

Comment: This doesn't make sense, for each `i` there is only one value in `p_hat[i]` and you cannot bootstrap one number. (I mean, you can but its mean equals that one number).

Comment: Also, put the function definition outside the `for` loop, you are recreating it over and over again.

Comment: @RuiBarradas it doesn't work for me anyway. Could you please help                  intervals  <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = length(p_hat))

my_function <- function(data, index) {
  return(median(data[index]))


for (i in 1:length(p_hat)) {
  boot_samples <- boot(p_hat[i], my_function, R = B)
  intervals[i,] <- boot.ci(boot_samples, type = "bca", conf = .9)
}
}

Comment: Please don't post code or data as comments, edit the question with that code. And yes, that's what I mean with my second comment. And in my first comment I explained ***the main objection*** to what you are doing. You cannot bootstrap values one by one. You can bootstrap the ***vector*** mean, the the mean value of each point individually.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  sorry, but I still don't understand how I can build confidence intervals for each point in the vector

Comment: You cannot. What is an interval around one point? A confidence interval assumes the existence of variability in the data, measured by the standard error. ***One*** point does not vary, the concept of confidence interval does not apply. (Note: there is a typo in the end of my previous comment, *"the the"*  is wrong, it should be *"not the mean value of each point individually."*

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(boot)

p_hat <- c(0, 0, 6.70881, 14.16335, 26.08988, 41.33073, 57.23204, 
           74.02023, 88.54585, 95.48473, 98.97599, 99.90797, 
           99.94741, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)

boot_mean <- function(x, i) mean(x[i])

alpha <- 0.9
b <- boot(p_hat, boot_mean, R = 5000)
ci <- boot.ci(b, conf = alpha)
#> Warning in boot.ci(b, conf = alpha): bootstrap variances needed for studentized
#> intervals

intervals <- lapply(ci[4:7], \(x) {
  ci <- setNames(tail(x[1,], 2), c("lower", "upper"))
  c(x[1, 1], ci)
})
do.call(rbind, intervals)
#>         conf    lower    upper
#> normal   0.9 53.94825 83.14039
#> basic    0.9 54.25572 83.31273
#> percent  0.9 53.78274 82.83975
#> bca      0.9 52.50008 82.01524
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>